# How do I get number of frames from the m4a file?

Tags: python, pydub, audiosegment

I want to open the m4a audio file for analysis but I am getting this error.

```
  File "E:\audio stego\code.py", line 5, in <module>
    song = AudioSegment.from_file('E:\\audio stego\\03 VALNDALUM UMMODU.m4a')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: If your error is `FileNotFoundError`, I think you should comment about the file and is it really there...

Comment: It is there in the same directory still getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't avconv installed or in your `PATH`.
To install it, you can follow these steps:
https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#getting-ffmpeg-set-up

If you're on windows, there are a few steps to add the folder to your `PATH`:

1. Download the latest version of Libav here: http://builds.libav.org/windows/release-gpl/ (don't pick the `mingw` versions if you don't know what they do)
2. Extract everything from the archive (you can use a free tool like WinRar or PeaZip)
3. Move the folder to your user one:

   - Right-click on the extracted `libav` folder
   - Click `Cut`
   - Press your `windows` key and your `R` key at the same time
   - Type in `%userprofile%`. Another window will open
   - Right click on an empty space and press `Paste`
4. Search with the search bar `environ` and click on `Edit system variables`.
5. Click on `Environment variables...`. You find two panels: one with `User Variables for [user]` and one with `System Variables`.
6. In the `User Variables` panel, find the `Path` variable and double-click it.
7. Click on `New` and enter `%USERPROFILE%\libav\bin`.
8. Press `Ok` on every window to close them.
9. Log out and log in back adn you're done!